# Why Does My Fluid Sim Suddenly Explode?

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I've been fighting with this sim all week. After attempting mantaflow for literally years now I still don't have a handle on how it behaves.  Is it mantaflow, or is it me!?

That said, I have a basic fluid sim setup and for no reason the mesh suddenly explodes as if there is a force or invisible boundary affecting it.  Yet there is not.

If anyone could open this project and just let me know what I'm missing I would be forever grateful.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/93ojbwru101l1iv/Fluid%20Why.blend?dl=0)

It starts out fine:
[image]

Then a few frames in it suddenly goes crazy:
[image]

Comment: The instability could be related to enabling the Viscosity feature. There is a current bug report about this here: https://developer.blender.org/T102755

With Viscosity enabled, I get similar unstable results. Disabling viscosity seems to result in a correct flow.

Comment: Ah man, thank you for this!  I get so overwhelmed with all the other glitches that I totally forgot about the viscosity bug (which I did read about before but forgot).  Now if I could figure out why the voxel size, domain size, and baking cache are so fickle my life would be complete ;)

Comment: @RLGUY If you want to write your comment as an answer I will mark it accordingly, thanks

Comment: Hey @RLGUY I just noticed that you are developer of the FLIP Fluids add-on.  I'm installing the demo now to see if it works.  Quick question- how does scale affect a fluid sim using the plugin?  In other words, can I work on a small scene that has a domain size of roughly 12-inches, or should I work at a larger scale?

Comment: The addon simulator should be able to handle small scales around 12-inches, but may require changing some settings for better results (tips in documentation: https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Domain-World-Settings#tips-on-simulating-small-world-sizes). Scaling larger can sometimes be easier to work with if the end result is intended to be in slow motion. Feel free to contact us with questions at support [at] flipfluids [dot] com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instability may be related to enabling the Viscosity feature. There is a current bug report about this here: https://developer.blender.org/T102755

With Viscosity enabled, I get similar unstable results. Disabling viscosity seems to result in a correct flow.